# Merge MySQL Duplicates and Keeping Content

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table that looks like this:

```
ID   Email
1    xx@xx.com
1    yy@yy.com
1    zz@zz.com
2    aa2@aa.com
2    bb@bb.com
```

I would like to merge by ID but keep the "Email" data in the same cell:

```
ID   Email
1    xx@xx.com, yy@yy.com, zz@zz.com
2    aa2@aa.com, bb@bb.com
```

How would you advise me to do that?

Comment: you have rows with duplicate id's!? how did that happen

Comment: Each ID represents an email ID.

Comment: Have you tried something so far?

Comment: No, I know how to remove duplicates but not how to keep the emails in one cell.

Comment: I'd suggest performing the logic in the application layer, not the database.

Comment: Not tested but check it:

UPDATE table AS t1 SET Email = (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Email) FROM table AS t2 WHERE t1.id = t2.id GROUP BY id)

After that remove duplicates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
  "INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE (ID, EMAIL) 
      SELECT ID, GROUP_CONCAT(EMAIL)AS EMAIL 
      FROM OLD_TABLE 
      GROUP BY ID"
```